# iOS Firebase configuration generates network activity

Tags: ios, firebase, privacy

I have an iOS app, and recently updated the Firebase SDK (for analytics and crash reporting).  Our app has opt-in tracking only, so no tracking can occur without consent.

Per instructions, I have these keys in the app's Info.plist:

```
<key>FirebaseCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled</key>
<false/>
<key>FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED</key>
<false/>
```

I also have code that does not execute `[FIRApp configure]` until the user has consented.

When I run my app, I get a rapidly-repeating warning before configuration:

```
6.31.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization. Read more: [Google's URL].
```

This warning repeats every few milliseconds.

The only way I can get rid of this warning is by running `[FIRApp configure]` for all users at launch.  However this fires off an immediate network connection to Google at https://app-measurement.com/sdk-exp, which is a violation of the tracking requirement.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this conflict, short of removing Firebase entirely?

Answer (score 0):

That warning is occurring because a Firebase call is being made before `[FIRApp configure]`. You could update your code to avoid that call until you know that `configure` has been called. To find the call(s), set a breakpoint at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseCore/Sources/FIRApp.m#L245.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using the pre-built library, but was able to find the call (`[[FIRCrashlytics crashlytics] setUserID:userID]`).  I wrapped logic around that to prevent using this before configuration.  However, even without any configuration of FIRApp I'm still seeing network requests to Google's server.  Any thoughts on a means to disable this entirely?

Comment: See discussion at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5837